# Hash rate of "Antminer S9" in "Antpool.com" is ZERO

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, asic, antminer, asicminer

I setup an **Antminer S9** using this document: ([**Link to document**](https://www.antminerdistribution.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/AntMiner-S9-Installation-Guide.pdf)).

And I configured connection to **antpool.com** using this guideline: ([**Link to guideline**](https://support.bitmain.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000211774-Connect-Antminer-S9i-S9-T9-S7-to-Pools-Antpool-BTC-com)).

So, I filled out the fields as follows:

```
Pool 1:

URL: stratum+tcp://stratum.antpool.com:3333

Worker: MySubAccountNameInAntpool.com.mywork

etc ...

Pool 2:  stratum+tcp://stratum.antpool.com:443
Pool 3: stratum+tcp://stratum.antpool.com:25
```

And when I **PING** to **antpool.com**, no packet is lost as follows:

[image]

However, when I see **Miner Status**, there is **no information** ! (as follows:)

[image]

Also, my hash rate in my dashboard in www.antpool.com is **zero** !

[image]

**What is the problem?**

*(If you need any further information, please let me know.)*

Comment: Can you share the settings tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In fact, although the PING to `Antpool.com` was successful; however, the network used a proxy causing problem of connecting successfully to Antpool.com. So, after changing the network I could see the hash rate in my dashboard.